# How can I create an array of instances accessible in a class?

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a code that create an array of instances of Account object in another class (`Bank`).

I am initializing the array inside the main method, but it is not accessible inside the `Bank` class.
What I want to do is create 4 instances of the `Account` class and to be able to perform all tasks inside the `Bank` class methods. Is there a way that I can do this?

this is my code

## Account.java

```
package question1;

import java.util.Date;

public class Account {

    public int AccountNum;
    public double BALANCE;
    public Date OPENDATE;
    public String OwnerName;

    public Account() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Account(int accnum, double balance, Date opendate, String ownername) {

        this.AccountNum = accnum;
        this.BALANCE = balance;
        this.OPENDATE = opendate;
        this.OwnerName = ownername;

    }

    public int getAccountNum() {
        return AccountNum;
    }

    public void setAccountNum(int accountNum) {
        AccountNum = accountNum;
    }

    public double getBALANCE() {
        return BALANCE;
    }

    public void setBALANCE(double bALANCE) {
        BALANCE = bALANCE;
    }

    public Date getOPENDATE() {
        return OPENDATE;
    }

    public void setOPENDATE(Date oPENDATE) {
        OPENDATE = oPENDATE;
    }

    public String getOwnerName() {
        return OwnerName;
    }

    public void setOwnerName(String ownerName) {
        OwnerName = ownerName;
    }

    public double yearlyInterest(double balace) {
        return balace;
    }
}
```

## Bank.java

```
package question1;

public class Bank  {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Account[] acc = new Account[4];

        for(int i = 0 ; i<acc.length; i++){
            acc[i] = new Account();
            System.out.println(acc[i].toString());

        }

        /// how to continue form here ??


    }


}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you asking.

Comment: I don´t really get you your question

Comment: i have a class Account and another one BanK ... I need to create a array of Account in Bank

Comment: @devleb "I need to create a array of Account in Bank" you already have it. What do you want to do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the constructor of the `Account` class. Now you can set all arguments as desired. Afterwards, you can add the instance to any array or collection.

```
List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account>(4);

Account myAccount = new Account(123, 100.5, new Date(), "dev leb");
accounts.add(myAccount);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to have a **property** of an `Account` array in your class.

You can set your property in the class body:

```
public class Bank {

  //Set your property here.
  private Account[] _acc;

  //Initialize in ctor.
  public Bank() {
    _acc = new Account[4];
  }
  //....
  //You can then use it as a property in your code.

  //If needed outside the class, set up setter and getter methods,
  //avoiding violating encapsulation.
  public Account[] getAcc(){
    return _acc;
  }

  public void setAcc(Account acc){
    this._acc = acc;
  }

  //If you need this to be used inside main, then you must instantiate a
  //Bank in main and then make all the appropriate operations there.
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Bank bank = new Bank();
    Account[] bankAccounts = bank.getAcc();
    //....
  }

}
```

My suggestion though is that you use an `ArrayList` instead:
Set the property:

```
private List<Account> acc;
```

And in constructor:
    acc = new List();

In order to add an account in a class method:

```
acc.add(new Account());
```

In order to retrieve an element by indexing:

```
acc.get(0);
```

for more information, look at the [ArrayList JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

If you are not able to understand why your array that is defined inside the main is not accessible inside your `Bank` class, then I suggest you search more about Object-Oriented programming, Class definition, instantiation and properties accessibility and manipulation and static methods in Java.